# Detecting convergence in Random walk

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, random-walk

I am trying to detect convergence of a random walk on a graph. After doing some preliminary research, the Geweke convergence diagnostic seems to be most commonly used for this.
This diagnostic calls for the z-score of the chain at each iteration of the walk and declares convergence when the z-score falls within an interval of [-1, 1].
The z-score is calculated thusly:
$$
z=\frac{E(X_a)-E(X_b)}{\sqrt{Var(X_a)+Var(X_b)}}
$$
where $X_a$ and $X_b$ are two subsequences of the current chain, typically the first 10% and the last 50% of the chain.

My dataset is a dense crawl of a social network where each node is a user.
My question is: in this context, what would the expected values of the subchains $X_a$ and $X_b$ be? Would it be the lengths, or a function of the lengths and degrees of the nodes or something else?